# Is there a catalog manager for Drupal?

Tags: drupal

I am building a product review site, is there a catalog manager module or third party catalog manager that works for Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

You could fairly easily put one together with the major Drupal modules - a little CCK, a little Views, and you'd be well on your way. One of the beauties of Drupal and its modules is that most of them are generalist enough that you can combine them into a nicely functional system.

Answer (score 0):

Views is likely what you are looking for: with no code in the beginning, you'll be able to build all sorts of lists, by type, by tag... You are likely to be especially interested in the views arguments, which allow you to refine a general list, or return to the general list from the refined one.

You can use the product listing features in drupal e-Commerce or Ubercart without having to enable the reste of the features. However, unless you really plan on enabling these features later on, this is probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Directory](https://www.drupal.org/project/directory) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... presents a very simple and lightweight hierarchical 'directory-like' view (conceptually similar to DMOZ, Yahoo, etc.) of nodes that have been assigned to one or more designated taxonomy 'vocabularies' (depending on module configuration). This allows users to drill down on selected content on your Drupal site.
>
> If you have a site with taxonomies already in place, and/or you are not using the category module, this module may be a simpler approach to hierarchical navigation - just drop it in, configure, and go.

You'll probably have to hack the module to change some small details you don't like, but other than that, it's pretty solid.